# Adding row content in report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

So i have this report viewer - i have a table which contains my data based on my stored procedure. i have 5 rows in my report each line containing a certain number - i have a totals line which should calculate the total amount based on the above line amounts like so :

line 1 : 20 
line 2 : 4
line 3 : 12
line 4 : 1
line 5 : 10
Totals : 47

I tried the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!TotalResults.Value)
```

But i get a much greater number which seems to be counting for none showing lines. 
How can i get the total for just the showing lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're choosing to display only certain rows based on an expression, you can use this same expression in your calculation.

For example, let's say you have a `Visibility` expression on the row that looks like this ("display the field only if XYZ is greater than 3"):

```
=iif(Fields!XYZ.Value>3, true, false)
```

Adapt your `Sum` aggregate to include the conditional, like this ("Sum only the values of TotalResults where XYZ is greater than 3"):

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!XYZ.Value>3, 0, Fields!TotalResults.Value))
```

Replace `Fields!XYZ.Value>3` with your own visibility condition, of course.

If this doesn't solve your problem, give us some more information about how you're determining which rows to display and maybe that will help. :)